# Excel 2013: Multiple Search Criteria for Row Index Array

Tags: excel

My Function:

=INDEX(MASTER!C:C,SMALL(INDEX((""=MASTER!A:A)*(MATCH(ROW(MASTER!A:A), ROW(MASTER!A:A)))+(""<>MASTER!A:A)*1048577,),$A31))

The Objective:

To get a value from a row in another table depending on if the "search group" of that row matches. Each one of these rows includes extra information, in separate columns, about a single entity.

The Problem:

I am able to create a "search group" array for a single group, but I would like to include multiple "search groups" in one array.

For Example:

If the other table was laid out as such:

```
Group Fruit   Person
G     Banana  Alex
L     Apple   Tim
P     Orange  Fred
```

My function above only searches for a blank "search group" label. If my sheet were to be this example, I would like to include "G" and "P" in my "row search".

The first sheet of this example could then look like this:

- Group Fruit   Person
- G     Banana  Alex
- P     Orange  Fred

Or this:

- Group Person  Fruit
- G     Alex    Banana
- P     Orange  Fred

depending on how the function was written. Notice that the rows don't change, which can be attributed to "SMALL" in my function. Also, the reference MASTER!A:A is the "search group", and MASTER!C:C is an information field.

Comment: can there be multiple 'G's and'P's to return?

Comment: Yes there can @MacroMarc